# how to read text records long and short using SAS?

Tags: input, sas

A text with 10 records need to read and save as a table, and the following is what I tried:
I split the records into 3 parts x1,x2,x3, but something wrong with x3:

```
data a;
input x1 $1-11 x2 $13-14 x3 $17-100;
cards;
Major Group 01: Agricultural Production Crops
Major Group 02: Agriculture Production Livestock And Animal Specialties
Major Group 07: Agricultural Services
Major Group 08: Forestry
Major Group 09: Fishing, Hunting, And Trapping
Major Group 10: Metal Mining
Major Group 37: Transportation Equipment
Major Group 38: Measuring, Analyzing, And Controlling Instruments, Photographic, Medical And 
Optical Goods, Watches And Clocks
Major Group 39: Miscellaneous Manufacturing Industries
Major Group 40: Railroad Transportation
;
run;
```

the result for x3 is truncated, and wonder how can I read the records correctly that can keep all the 10 records without missing any single letter.
thanks!

Comment: I see two variables, "Major Group 01" and "Agricultural Production Crops" for the first row. What do you want as the third variable?

Comment: Note that your have an EOL character or something specified after Major Group = 38. Usually returns have different characters than EOL and if that's the case here you can also provide the EOL character to the INFILE statement as well to ensure that line is ready correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use fixed width format, use a delimited approach with the colon as a delimiter
2. Specify a length for the variables

```
data a;
length x1 $20 x2 $100.;
infile cards dlm=':' truncover;
input x1 x2;
*separate group type and number into two different variables;
GroupNum = input(compress(x1, , 'kd'), 8.);
GroupType = compress(x1, , 'd');
cards;
Major Group 01: Agricultural Production Crops
Major Group 02: Agriculture Production Livestock And Animal Specialties
Major Group 07: Agricultural Services
Major Group 08: Forestry
Major Group 09: Fishing, Hunting, And Trapping
Major Group 10: Metal Mining
Major Group 37: Transportation Equipment
Major Group 38: Measuring, Analyzing, And Controlling Instruments, Photographic, Medical And Optical Goods, Watches And Clocks
Major Group 39: Miscellaneous Manufacturing Industries
Major Group 40: Railroad Transportation
;
run;
```